# How can I access AWS ECS containers?

Tags: amazon-ecs

I have a task running a container in AWS ECS. There doesn't seam to be any ECS CLI commands to access that container. Is is possible to log directly into a container running in ECS?

Comment: ssh into container instance, run `docker ps` to get container id,
then run `docker exec -it [container id] bash` (if your container using bash as shell)

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I will try it. Do you know if its also possible to access a container hosted by Fargate ?

Comment: i'm afraid it is not possible, i have been tried that before. It's the security policy from AWS. I dunno if they have change it tough.

Comment: Could you try install ssh service on ecs forget.this way might be possible  https://docs.docker.com/engine/examples/running_ssh_service/.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can access the ECS container if you deployed using AWS - ECS - EC2 option. You can get the container IP from the ECS - ECS instances tab and SSH into the instance to see it there. Make sure the Security Group of this instance allows SSH access. Let me know if this helps!